# Symfony2 - SQL query returns different result set than direct query in DB

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I've got a strange issue. I'm testing results relevance with this query:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    title,
    MATCH (title) AGAINST (:searchNormal ) AS relevance
FROM
    movie
WHERE
    MATCH (title) AGAINST (:searchModified IN BOOLEAN MODE)
HAVING relevance > 0.2
ORDER BY relevance DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Not worrying about user input sanitizing yet,

`:searchNormal` is just

```
trim($searchQuery)
```

and

`:searchModified` is

```
'+' . str_replace(' ', '+', trim($searchQuery)
```

I use it like this:

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$statementData = array(
    'searchNormal' => trim($searchQuery),
    'searchModified' => '+' . str_replace(' ', '+', trim($searchQuery))
    );

$statement = $entityManager->getConnection()->prepare($SQLquery);
$statement->execute($statementData);
```

**Results on local machine:**

When I run the SQL query directly on DB engine on my local machine, it works great. For example, phrases ***green kill*** AND ***kill green*** both return one result, "The Long Green Kill". The same happens when I run the code.
Both in `dev` and `prod` Symfony envs.

**Results in production:**

When I run it on production machine directly on DB, it also works. **BUT** when I run the code, it returns messy result. "The Long Green Kill" is on top only for phrase "green kill" and below there are hundreds of records, depending on the first word in search query, either with "green" or "kill" in title.
I wouldn't be surprised if it was working on one machine the same (wrong or right) way both on DB and through PHP, but this is strange. Do you have any ideas, what may have happened?